# Simular hint de EditText en TextInputLayout JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout"
            style="@style/CajasDeTexto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/input_background"
            android:src="@drawable/show_password_selector"
            android:textColorHint="@color/blanco"
    
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:hint="@string/placeHolderTxtContrasena"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
            app:passwordToggleTint="@color/blanco">
        
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtContrasena"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Lo que provoca que al escribir se vea asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al escribir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que el HINT desaparezca/ no se vea como cuando empieze a escribir en el y aparesca cuando no tenga nada en la caja tal como funciona con el Edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si no he entendido mal lo que que quieres es que el label flotante, desaparezca, y que solo esté el hint normal.

Solo hay que añadir dos líneas en el diseño:

1. Añadimos la propiedad `app:hintEnabled="false"` en el TextInputLayout.
2. Añadimos el hint al EditText y un color para que se vea.

   `android:hint="password"`

   `android:textColorHint="#fff"`

Con ello conseguiremos lo que buscas.
Te dejo el código y unas capturas.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout"
        style="@style/CajasDeTexto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_background"
        android:src="@drawable/show_password_selector"
        android:textColorHint="@color/blanco"
        app:hintEnabled="false"

        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:hint="@string/placeHolderTxtContrasena"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/blanco">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtContrasena"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:hint="password"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"/>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: captura1]

[image: captura2]

¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Lo chequeo y te aviso estimado gracias

Answer (score 2):

El elemento que no deseas mostrar se llama `Label` (etiqueta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este elemento se agrega con esta propiedad:

```
  android:hint="@string/placeHolderTxtContrasena"
```

por lo tanto si no deseas que se muestre deseas debes eliminarla.

El problema aquì es que el texto mostrado en el `Label` y el "hint" del `EditText` son definidos por la misma propiedad, por lo tanto puedes dejar de mostrar el `Label` y continuar mostrando el "hint" del `EditText` de esta forma:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
       inputLayout.setHint(hasFocus ? "" : "Contraseña");
    }
});
```

Comment: Mmm si escribo en la caja de texto aun muestra el "Contrasena" siempre creo no es funcional del todo

Comment: Luego de varias pruebas no puedo generar el efecto deseado se agradece el intento